# How to manage dbId properly in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In three.js the id is autogenerated, but the dbId for objects in the viewer seems to require to be manualy be inserted when creating a new object for the viewer, and it needs to be unique, it can't have the same dbId that a object generated by the viewer or a object inserted manually. What I want to ask, what is the ideal way to generate a random unique dbId, or the proper way to manage dbId in the forge viewer.

I have been looking online, but really the only thing I found is that it needs to be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVF dbids are simply generated as incremental integers, so if you'd like to follow that same approach, you could get the highest existing dbid, and start incrementing from there, for example, like so:

```js
const tree = viewer.model.getInstanceTree();
let nextAvailableID = tree.objectCount + 1;
function generateID() { return nextAvailableID++; }
```

Comment: I see, this seems like a good solution, but, in case I upload a second model after I did what you suggest, I think it would make the dbid of the objects of the new model be the same that the ones I got with generateID()?

Comment: What do you think  about decreassing instead of increasing the ids? something like this 


l

Comment: let nextAvailableID = 8388607;
function generateID() { return nextAvailableID--; }

Comment: The number 8388607 is the max dbid number I was able to get without breaking it, maybe there are better numbers to start with?

Comment: Well... now that you mention it, the dbIDs are actually only required to be unique within its own model. So theoretically, when you create a new, custom model, you _might_ be able to start counting from 1. But of course, if you then want to access some specific object, you will need to reference it using both its dbID and its corresponding model.

Comment: I see, then I can start giving it the id I want, and only making sure its unique from the others ids I will be inserting into the viewer. That will make everthing a lot more simple, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid), or jQuery uuid() library for this. Another option is to have your own implementation, see an example below (which works but not the best approach if you want unique ID persistent which isn't your case here).

```
function getUUID() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, 
    function(c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d/16);
        return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
};
```

Comment: This does not work. The dbid from viewer internal objects seems to only accept numbers with a max value of 8388607. Objects generated by the viewer seems to have numbers with 6 digits. I could do a Math.random()*1000000 and it would accept the 6 digit number, the problem with this implementation is that at some point the viewer will end up having 2 objects with the same id since there is no unique check and a 6 digit number is a small number

Comment: Hold-on, are you talking about Three.js or the Forge Viewer? You cannot add Viewer object scenes like this. The id must follow certain rules. The propertDB object has a property to find the idMax value, and you will need to increment it as well, but it also mean you need to create property entries and so on. I can certainly  assit you to do this, but why an overlay three.js object no enough?

Comment: Right now I'm working with Sprites from the [Data Visualization extension](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/introduction/). I have been looking into using THREE sprites, but I found easier to work with the one in the Data Visualization since is better integrated into the viewer and has already the events I need for them (onSpriteHovering and onSensorSpriteClicked)

Comment: I see, I'll ask my colleagues to help - this is very specific